# Android InflateException Binary XML file line #2

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm trying to get my activity working, but I keep getting the exception below:

```
02-20 00:27:33.060 30161-30161/com.m2gl.runandshare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.m2gl.runandshare, PID: 30161
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m2gl.runandshare/com.m2gl.runandshare.SummaryWorkoutActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2739)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2272)
  at com.m2gl.runandshare.SummaryWorkoutActivity.onCreate(SummaryWorkoutActivity.java:66)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6368)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436) 
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2272) 
  at com.m2gl.runandshare.SummaryWorkoutActivity.onCreate(SummaryWorkoutActivity.java:66) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6368) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/secondary_text_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060005
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3761)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3629)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3991)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:507)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:191)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436) 
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2272) 
  at com.m2gl.runandshare.SummaryWorkoutActivity.onCreate(SummaryWorkoutActivity.java:66) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6368) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:180)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1170)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1083)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3745)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3629) 
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762) 
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3991) 
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:507) 
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199) 
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195) 
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:191) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:436) 
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2272) 
  at com.m2gl.runandshare.SummaryWorkoutActivity.onCreate(SummaryWorkoutActivity.java:66) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6368) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

I know that this exception is about my layout XML file, I also know that a common problem is using big sized images and getting an out of memory problem, but I use xml files for my icons and they are so small.
Since my layout is very big here's a link to a Gist with the layout code: [Layout Code](https://gist.github.com/vivitarjos/9ac53b0ed87df6c5baf7)

Comment: It might help to include said layout XML.

Comment: I edited the question thanks

Comment: Please include any code, XML, and/or logcat output directly within the question.

Comment: I really tried but it's a huge file, anyway thank you for your help, i found a solution for the problem and i post the answer for anyone having the same issue.

Comment: "I really tried but it's a huge file" - Understood. In the future, perhaps it might help to at least pare it down to just what's needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that the background of my LinearLayout doesn't really support colors as a path android:color... I just changed it to my local colors file using @colors/.. and everything worked just like a charm. Thanks