# SystemUI force stopped

Tags: java, android, xml

What's the problem,my systemui forced stop every time..my Catlog

```
11-16 22:00:22.537 E/AndroidRuntime(566): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.android.systemui flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } in com.android.server.WallpaperManagerService$MyPackageMonitor@41a43e98
11-16 22:00:30.382 E/AndroidRuntime(676):   at com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine.drawFrameLocked(ImageWallpaper.java:467)
11-16 22:00:30.382 E/AndroidRuntime(676):   at com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine.drawFrameLocked(ImageWallpaper.java:571)
11-16 22:00:30.382 E/AndroidRuntime(676):   at com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine.onVisibilityChanged(ImageWallpaper.java:343)
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.systemui.SystemUIService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.adi.rom.interface.LGxMusicControls
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.makeStatusBarView(PhoneStatusBar.java:460)
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addStatusBarWindow(PhoneStatusBar.java:3066)
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.createAndAddWindows(PhoneStatusBar.java:3041)
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.start(BaseStatusBar.java:223)
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.start(PhoneStatusBar.java:424)
11-16 22:00:50.125 E/AndroidRuntime(14691):     at com.android.systemui.SystemUIService.onCreate(SystemUIService.java:105)
```

Comment: Is this really the full stacktrace? Have you googled for the exception message *"Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class"* and checked the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android InflateException Binary XML file line #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517118/android-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2)

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM ?

Comment: Add your xml file please alongside main class onCreate Code snippet

Comment: @Tom I am new in stackoverflow.. and i am a simple themer

Comment: @Smartiz No this is my base rom and i tried to edit my systemui to add LGX Music on statusbar expanded ..& it is a JB rom